# py2neo v4 create a relationship with 2 existing node in database

Tags: python-3.x, neo4j, py2neo

i have this problem

With py2neo how can I create a relationship between 2 existing nodes in my database select them using the id.
In the py2neo documentation I find only examples that create the nodes at the moment and associate them directly with merge

I try this in my code:

```
db = conn()
data = DataFrame(db.run("MATCH (n:personalesanitario) RETURN ID(n) LIMIT 100").data())
x = 0
WORKIN = Relationship.type("WORKIN")
while (x <= 99):
    #print(data['ID(n)'][x])
    n1 =  db.evaluate("MATCH (n:personalesanitario) WHERE ID(n) = $id RETURN 1",parameters = {'id':int(data['ID(n)'][x])})
    print(n1)
    n2 = db.evaluate("MATCH (n:reparti) WHERE ID(n) = $id RETURN 1",parameters = {'id':randint(101,109)})
    #print(n2)
    db.merge(WORKIN(n1,n2))
    x = x+1
```

Comment: What's the issue? Are you getting any error?

Comment: yes,this:
  File "C:\Python37\lib\site-packages\py2neo\data.py", line 822, in apply
    raise TypeError("Cannot cast %s to Node" % obj.__class__.__name__)
TypeError: Cannot cast int to Node

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `return 1` to `Return n` in those two queries.

It's not returning node but string.